# Else statement for user authentication did not effect

Tags: php

I have this php code for authenticating user account, The foreach loop effects and logs the user to adminhome.php and in my else statement, it sends them back to index.php with an error1 that says account has wrong password. But it doesn't. Did I miss something?

authenticate.php

```
<?php
require 'database-config.php';
session_start();

$username = "";
$password = "";

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $password = $_POST['password'];

}

$q = "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username=:username";

$query = $dbh->prepare($q);
$query->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
$results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );


    foreach( $results as $row ){ 
    if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){

        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $row['username'];
        $_SESSION['sess_name'] = $row['name'];
        $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] = $row['user_role'];

        echo $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
        session_write_close();

            header('Location: adminhome.php');
    }
    else 
    {
        header('Location: index.php?err=1');
    }
    }


 ?>
```

Comment: `header(); exit();` i how it should be looking. Also, if a username does not exist then the if statement will be ignored since the foreach statement will not execute with no rows

Comment: where should I put these in the line sir? and also how can I query if the user doesnt exist? can you please tell me how

Comment: i think, you should first check if `result` not empty and it is array. if it is not array or it is empty then foreach will not execute.

Comment: thanks to both of you sir! I understood the flow for this one now. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is, if there are no rows returned from your SQL query - the `foreach` statement does not execute. Your if statement sits inside of your `foreach` statement. When pulling data out of the database, you can use `PDOStatement::fetch` if you know the query will return only one row, in your case - I assume username is unique.

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username=:username";

$query = $dbh->prepare($q);
$query->execute(array(':username' => $username));
# You only need to pull one row here, no usernames should be duplicates
$row = $query->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

To then test the row exists (username was found) you can simply use `if($row)` then go through your normal checking.

```
if($row)
{
    if(password_verify($password, $row['password']))
    {
        // Continue your code
    }

}

header('Location: index.php?err=1');
exit();
```

Comment: Thank you sir! you saved my life! I've been wondering how to get pass these for an hour :(

Comment: Hope it helped! :)

Comment: Did so much! :)

Comment: I gathered recently that OP prefers to have the code complete in the answer so he can copy and paste and if it works: just accept. They don’t care about the explanation as much, but if it helps future viewers, I’m not too fussed but you’re right lol Idk either @Nick

Answer (score 1):

You should first check if there is any row. Update your query fetch to:

```
$query->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

and then check if it is not empty:

```
if(!empty($result) && is_array($result)){
    foreach( $results as $row ){ 
        if(password_verify($password, $row['password'])){

            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['sess_user_id'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['sess_username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['sess_name'] = $row['name'];
            $_SESSION['sess_userrole'] = $row['user_role'];

            echo $_SESSION['sess_userrole'];
            session_write_close();

            header('Location: adminhome.php');
        }else{
            header('Location: index.php?err=1');
        }
    }
}else{
    // user not found
}
```